# Add field with dash character in Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to add a field to a schema which includes dash character (`-`) in it. Mongoose is not allowing it. Is this possible or not?

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
  family-name: {
    type: String, 
    default: ''
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add quotes around the property name:

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
  'family-name': {
    type: String, 
    default: ''
  }
});
```